# Generating Outbound Links To Main Website From Widget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, widget, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application that lives on server 1:

> http://www.mysite.com

And i've got a widget (also ASP.NET MVC 3 web application) that lives on server 2:

> http://widget.www.mysite.com

Now, i want to generate a link to the main website from my widget.

So if i do something like this in the widget project:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Outbound link", "MainWebsiteRoute", "http", "http://www.mysite.com", string.Empty, null)
```

It will error (or generate the wrong link) because the route tables are different between the widget and website project.

Even if i copy the route from the main website into the widget one, the controllers/actions don't exist in the widget project, so it won't work.

How do i do it? Do i have to hardcode the URL's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up duping the routes from the main website that i need in the widget.

Example route in main website:

```
context.MapRoute(
   "Q&A - Individual Q",
   "{locationUniqueUri}/questions/{questionUniqueUri}",
   new { controller = "Questions", action = "Detail" },
);
```

Duped route in widget:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
   "Outbound - Q&A - Individual Q",
   "{locationUniqueUri}/questions/{questionUniqueUri}"
);
```

Notice how there are no route defaults - that's because i don't care, since that's concerning matching the route to a controller/action. But this happens in the website, not the widget. All i'm concerned about is *generating* the URL.

I then created a simple wrapper for `RouteLink` called `OutboundRouteLink` which specifies the hostname (for the main website), and generates the link.

I don't think it's *too* bad a solution. Obviously, it's hard-coded in a way - if the routes change in the main website then i'll have to change the widget routes. But that fine, because if one of my URL's changed, i'd have to do 301's anyway, so the old URL's would still work for the widget (they would get 301'd).

Also, i could go one step further and store the route url in a config file and share that between the projects, which would give me a bit more safety. But there's only around 3 outbound URL's so this should be fine.

Not saying this is the *best* way to handle it, but im happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using areas?  If not, then perhaps you should be.  That way you could simply supply the area for the route and it would be able to resolve the url for you.  Given your sample URLs you could build your main site with your widget site as an area.  Supplying a empty string for the area parameter in the route values would allow you to reference a controller/action in the main site from the widget site.

Comment: Yes, but that changes the architecture of the two sites. They are seperate projects, for a few reasons - but that's out of the scope for this question. Your answer is predicated on the fact that they need to be a single web project - correct?

Comment: @RPM1984 - yep, they would need to be in the same project.  That's what allows you to reuse the routing setup between the two.

Comment: fair enough. Well that can't happen. How about a "base" web project where certain routes can be registered and inherited by the 2 projects..possible?

Comment: @RPM1984  you might want to think about creating a custom helper that uses a non-default set of routes and pulls the host name from a configuration file instead of the running application.  Poke around in the source on http://codeplex.com/aspnet to see if there's a way to adapt the existing helpers for your needs.